# Standard definition of list

Tags: list, haskell, types, syntax

I have a problem with definition of list. Normally is list defined as `data [a] = [] | a : [a]`
but if I write something like this on my code concrete I will to define `data T a = N | a -> (T a)` the interpreter give me an error:

> Malformed head of type or class declaration

Do you know what's wrong?
.

Answer (score 16):

It looks like your problem is that you tried to use `->` as an infix constructor like `:` (In order to build a list using `a -> b -> N` syntax). This isn't allowed because custom infix constructors in Haskell must begin with the `:` character.

The reason for your strange error message is because `->` in Haskell is reserved for function types, as [Jeff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597157/standard-definition-of-list/5597255#5597255) explains

Try this instead:

```
-- Create a right-associative infix constructor.
data T a = N | a :-> (T a)
infixr :->

mylist :: T Int
mylist = 10 :-> 17 :-> N

--If we hadn't made the operator right associative,
-- we would need to use explicit parenthesis here
myotherlist :: T Int
myotherlist = 10 :-> (17 :-> N)

-- Example function
isempty :: T a -> Bool
isempty N         = True
isempty (_ :-> _) = False
```

Comment: Emoticons look so much nicer than arrows.

Comment: Should `isempty N = True` ?

Comment: Indeed! Fixed it now.

Answer (score 8):

`a -> T a`  would mean that a is a function that returns something of `T a` so I think that's the bit that's wrong.  Try something like this.

```
data T a = N | R a (T a)
```

N is the empty list (equivalent of `[]`) value and R is the value constructor (equivalent to `:`)

On the right hand side you need some way of carrying the `a` value around.  You can now right lists like.

```
> N -- The empty List
> R 5 N -- a list with a single element and then the end
> R 7 (R 6 (R 5 N)) -- the list 7, 6, 5
```

Comment: Thank you, but i read that (->) is among others a data constructor. Really a will to define a function with no fixed count of arguments. For example funtion to sum their arguments: sum 5 = 5 ; sum 5 4 = 9 ... so I have to define a data structure using (->)

Comment: (->) is a *type* constructor, not a data constructor.  (->) takes two types (say, a and b) and returns a *type* representing a function from an object of type a to an object of type b.

Comment: @877: Defining a variadic function is somewhat difficult in Haskell: what would its type be?  It's possible (see the [`Text.Printf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Text-Printf.html) module), but it's rarely what you want.  The more usual solution is to have your function take a list.  And indeed, in the Prelude, there's a function [`sum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:sum) which has type `Num a => [a] -> a`.